# Javascript Mocha schedule one time test data cleanup

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am writing a mini-framework for executing unit tests for a product I work on.  I want test data to be published and managed as seamlessly as possible.  With Mocha, it is easy to schedule test data cleanup using the After() hook.

You could wrap an individual test in a describe() block and use that block's Before/After method, but that I'd rather avoid that if possible.

You could pass a cleanup function to afterEach which specifically targets data populated inside a test.  Though that would only be necessary for one cleanup and it seems clunky to do that.

Is it possible to generate test data within one test, just for the sake of that test, and also schedule a cleanup for it with Mocha?

Comment: 1. Do you have to generate a separate file? You could easily write a test data generation function, provided your test data is of a size manageable by memory. 2. Can you elaborate on what "that would only be necessary for one cleanup" means? What's wrong with `afterEach`?

Comment: To be more clear, my test data is populated in a database using Knex.  I want tests to be able to request data from helpers and have them populate the database and then clean it up after.  So if a test block inserts two entries to a table, precisely those two entries should be removed after the test run.  I can use their Primary Key to track them and clean them up in a targeted approach.  I could have afterEach do that, but it will run after every single test rather than the one time clean.

Comment: If you want to test the read/writes, I'd suggest a mocking tool, like the excellent [`mock-knex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mock-knex). Or you could easily write your own mock db that implements the methods you're testing and stores the entries in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just run your generation and cleanup in the test itself. If it's asynchronous, you can use the `done` callback to make it wait until it's called.

```js
mocha.setup('bdd');
describe('suite', function() {
  function getData() {
    // Simulate asynchronous data generation
    console.log('grabbing data');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(100), 500);
    });
  }

  function cleanup() {
    // Simulate asynchronous cleanup
    console.log('cleaning up...');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 500);
    });
  }

  it('should do generation and clean up', function(done) {
    // Generate some data
    getData()
      .then(data => {
        // Test the data
        if (data !== 100) {
          throw new Error('How?!');
        }

        console.log('test passed');

        // Cleanup
        return cleanup();
      })
      .then(_ => {
        // Use done() after all asynchronous work completes
        console.log('done cleaning');
        done();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Make sure it cleans up no matter what
        cleanup().then(_ => console.error(err));
      });
  });
});
mocha.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mochajs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
```

Comment: This might be the best approach.  I want to avoid explicitly having to call a cleanup method at the end of the test itself.  I have cleanup scheduled automatically in describe() level test data.  Developers might forget to clean it up explicitly in a single test since that is different, but this is a good way to do it.

Comment: @Akron That's the rub though. Either you specify the specific test which needs cleanup or just run a general cleanup and hope for the best. That's about what it comes down to, as far as I can tell. No matter what, you'll need to mark a test for cleanup *somehow* so there's always the possibility someone will forget to clean it up.

Answer (score 0):

I think cleanup after test is generally problematic because cleanup consistency guarantees aren't very strong, ie is cleanup function guaranteed to run? probably not.  If it's not assured that cleanup will take place then it could very well leave the next tests in an inconsistent state. I think it's good to make an attempt but you can guard against failure by:

- cleaning up/establishing db state BEFORE each test
- nuking the world so each test has a consistent state (can be accomplished by executing your test in the context of a transaction and rolling back the transaction after each test, and at least not ever committing the transaction)
- having test create unique data.  By leveraging unique data you can also run your tests in parallel, since it allows for multiple different tests to have an isolated view of the db.  If each test writes its own data you only have to worry about provisioning the whole db at the beginning of each test run

Of the above if you're able to wrap your test in a transaction it is lightning fast, (web frameworks like django and rails do this and it is quite fast and makes tests/db state very easy to reason about)